# How to clear text from a jtextarea, and then keep appending other text (with the same button)?

Tags: java, swing, append, actionlistener, jtextarea

I am trying to develop a simple calculator, where when the user keeps on clicking numbers, they appear on the textarea. If they click an operator ("+", "-", "*", etc), the number that was on the textarea, and the operator they click, they get saved on a number and operator variables respectively. When the user clicks another number after clicking the operator, it should remove the number that was at the jtextarea, and write the new number on it on it, so that I can store it on a second number variable and finally make an operation with both numbers.

The problem I'm facing, is that when the user clicks a number for the second time, i.e, after clicking the operator, I can't find a way to clear what was on the textarea, and also keep appending the numbers being clicked. If I put a code to clear the textarea and the append a number, all it does, is clear the previous number, and write **ONLY ONE NUMBER** , for instance, if I wanted to write "857" It can only write "8", and if I click "5", "8" gets cleared and "5" is written.

I understand and get why it doesn't work, because the clear and the append codes happen each time a user clicks a number. So I wanted to know if there is a way around that, and also if it is possible to: clear the text, and then keep appending a text, i.e, the second time a user clicks a number, it should append the number on the screen, not clear it.

Comment: When processing the press of an operator button, you must have set a reminder that the display should be cleared when accepting the next digit, yes?  So, did you then remember to _clear that reminder_ after the next digit input?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @KevinAnderson. Yes, that was the problem, I forgot to use that reminder properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda Thank you for your concern. I already found out, with the help of the community, that the main problem was the absence of a state variable which would allow the program to behave accordingly. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to approach my answer to this problem with two concepts in program design: the first is the design dependence on an external feature, and the second is a state machine.

I'm making some guesses and assumptions here, but from your description it appears that you have fastened onto the "append" feature of a text area and are now programming so that you can use it in a couple of situations: adding a number to the number on the display, and putting a new number in the display ('appending' to an empty display).

That is a nice feature of textarea, it might be useful for your program, but you don't have to use it here.

However you solve this problem, you have a 'state' to save -- when the user presses a key, the thing the program does depends on its state. You have to be able to discern what state it's in so that you can program the response to the keypress correctly.

So let me suggest this: have a variable that stores what you want in the display -- all of it. When someone presses a key, discern your state in whatever fashion and update that variable with what is supposed to be in the display. When you're done processing, set the text area to that variable's value.

Note that this allows the program flow -- receive input, process, display -- to be the same in all cases. No part of the program has to figure out whether to 'clear' the display. Because of that, there is less complexity in the state you are saving.

If your state is "accumulating numbers for first operand", and a number is pressed, then you append the number pressed to the string being displayed.

If your state is "accumulating..." and an operator is pressed, append the operator.

If your state is "operator just pressed" and another number is pressed, set the variable to the number pressed.

and so forth.

These may or may not be the correct states to use, I just have them here as simple examples. But done in some similar way, I think you'll find your program gets simpler to write and to understand -- you remove the code that interacts between the 'append' feature and the program's state, which was making your code more complicated than it needed to be.

It is very common, I've found, for programmers (including myself) to get attached to some implementation that we then work around -- in fact, we are always working around implementations to some extent, that's what we do. But sometimes if we take a step back, we can see that we are doing more programming working around some implementation detail that we can eliminate, and by eliminating it we can simplify our solution.

Comment: Well, you are definitely right. Somehow I got too attached to the "append()" method, that I forgot that I could use another approach here which, in fact, turns out to be a lot easier. Besides that, I think that the main point that solved my problem, was surely the need of a state variable, that allows the program to flow accordingly. Thank you for the suggestion and the time. It really helped. Kind regards!

Comment: Am glad it helped! On StackOverflow, if an answer is helpful, it is customary to upvote it; if an answer actually answers your question, it is customary to also mark it as an answer. This helps other people when they're searching for answers to their own questions, and distributes reputation points to people, etc. Welcome to the show that never ends...

Comment: Already did it. Thank you for the reception. I'll be looking forward to help, make questions and contribute as needed also. See you soon ;)

Comment: You say you did it, but the answer is still not marked as "an answer".

Comment: I don't know if it is because I'm new and don't have a big reputation yet (13), but I already clicked the tick, and right now it is green (or maybe I'm not doing the right way). I also tried to upvote, but whenever I try, they say: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". Maybe I'm not doing the right way. What can I do to turn this around. I'll be please to do. Cheers.

Comment: I beg your pardon, the check mark IS green, and of course your reputation prevents you from doing the upvote. I was glancing at it and getting it wrong. Good luck with your programming.

Comment: Wish you the same. Cheers!